# Leading zero were automatically removed from int data type field in solr so how to overcome this issue without using string data type

Tags: java, java-8, solr, solrcloud, solr4

We are using the **int data type** field in Solr. The value which we are trying to add is **0045**. While Solr inserts this value into that field it will automatically remove the preceding **'00'**. The value shown in Solr is **45**. Provide the solution to overcome this problem and add the data same as **0045** in Solr without changing **int** data type.

Original Value = **0045**

Current Value in Solr  =  **`<int> 45 </int>`**
Expected Value in Solr =  **`<int> 0045 </int>`**

**Note => We need to achieve the value with the Preceding zeros in Solr.**

Comment: There is no such thing as an int with leading zeros

Comment: Please elaborate your understanding of the "value" **0045**. Is it the octally represented decimal value 37? Is it the string consisting of characters which happen to be digits and starts with twice the character "0"? How important is the persistence of the representation in bold characters? Is the result of calculating the product of 9 by 5 the same integer value 45 in question here? These questions might be perceived a little cynical, in that case please accept my apology. I intend them to help you to change your angle of perceiving "0045" and open you to the concept of value representation.

Comment: Leading zeros have no meaning for numeric types *apart from* as a means of indicating octal literals in code

Comment: Have two fields. One as a string and one as an int, and use a `copyField` instruction to index it into both fields _if_ this is important to you _inside your Solr instance_. If not, format the integer on the way out to the expected format.

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you for your response. Whenever we are inserting this value in the Database value is **0045**. the value showing in the listing is also **0045**. but whenever we try to insert the value in **0045** it saves **45** in Solr. So how can we achieve **0045** in solr for same ?

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for your response. But if we are using `copyField` it leads to a large indexing space issue. So is there any other way to achieve the goal to save **0045** in Solr?

Comment: I see that you a) insist on bold b) insist on leading "00" c) cannot describe the desired value in any integer-related way. You only focus on seeing **0045** and cannot leave that focus to discuss possible integer values. So the impression I get is that you need to store that as a string and make sure that the presentation at least supports markdown. I.e. drop the `int` part of your code/html and switch to something string-oriented.

Comment: From your point of view, will you want to store more than one of `0045`, `045`, and `45` (or of course `00045` or any other number of leading zeroes)?

Comment: @Shubham This is a display issue, so format it in the frontend/template/etc. if you need to keep it as integer internally and don't only have four digit numbers. You _could_ write a custom response formatter in Solr that allows you to define formatting rules for certain fields, but it's going to be more work than just doing it in your existing frontend before displaying it to the user.